# List Metadata Missing CaseComment?

Tags: metadata, ant, platform-bug

Are there any restrictions on which standard objects are returned with a list metadata call for `CustomObject` or `Workflow`?

Taking a stab at fixing a [mavensmate bug](https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/issues/392) which builds it's project manager using list metadata calls. Turns on `CaseComment` isn't returned with either list `CustomObject` or list `Workflow` as of api v35. Everything works fine when I try to retrieve the CaseComment object and workflow, so doesn't seem like a limitation of the metadata api.

Hoping to figure out if this is a known limitation before dedicating the time to run this through salesforce support.